# Ruby installation issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I am trying to install the ruby version 2.3.5 in my mac OS environment which is Mojave. I am getting the following issues. Appreciate If anyone can help me to sort out the issue ?

```
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/efutures/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5
  --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  CFLAGS= -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32 
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/efutures/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/efutures/.rbenv/versions/2.3.5/include
```

I tried the following command.

```
rbenv install 2.3.5
```

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to install it? By what command(s)?  Are there online steps you are following? If so, what are they? It appears you are also using `rbenv`?

Comment: Yes I was following the below article.
https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave
I was trying with the following command as well.
rbenv install 2.3.5

Comment: It would help if you showed exactly what you entered at the command line in your question. Just the error out of context is less clear. There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58392508/edit) link below your question.

Comment: I updated my question with the command I tried in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Found an [issue in rbenv repo](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1030) which suggests that you need an extension to get rbenv to properly work.

Follow the instruction [here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) to install and get rbenv to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

`rbenv` is a ruby manager. It builds different `ruby` from source. To make it work, you need to install `rbenv` and `rbenv-build`.

```sh
brew install rbenv rbenv-build
```

Secondly, you need to install dependencies `readline` and `openssl@1.1`.

```sh
brew install realine openssl@1.1
```

The error `missing extensions` is related to `ruby-build`, you may forget to install it or the dependencies.